# Using .loc[index] to set a rows value by index and add any additional columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to use .loc[] to set a rows value (using a series) as well as add any additional columns that might exist in this series. Perhaps there is a type of merge I am unaware of that could merge a series into a dataframe by index.

```
import pandas as pd
index = 1
series = pd.Series({'a':2, 'b':54, 'c':945})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'b': {0: 3, 1: 54, 2: 1}})
df.loc[index] = series
```

output:

```
   a   b
0  1   3
1  2  54
2  3   1
```

Desired output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  3  
1  2  54 945
2  3  1
```

Comment: `df.loc[:,'c'] = series`

Comment: @rhug123 this only creates a new column called `c` with all values as NaN

Comment: my apologies, i didnt read the question close enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index of the series as columns:

```
>>> df.loc[index, series.index] = series
>>> df
   a   b      c
0  1   3    NaN
1  2  54  945.0
2  3   1    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the dataframe first:

```
df2 = df.reindex(columns=series.index)
df2.loc[index] = series
```

Alternatively, use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df2 = df.combine_first(series.to_frame(name=index).T)
```

output:

```
   a   b      c
0  1   3    NaN
1  2  54  945.0
2  3   1    NaN
```